# Collect agent attributes from agents in queue

Tags: anylogic

I have a queue block where agents enter and exit. Each agent has the following attributes (parameters): ID, processing time and due date. After one hour, I want to use an event block to collect the info (ID,processing time and due date) of the agents that are still waiting in the queue at that moment, and write this info to Excel. In Excel, I would like 3 columns, one with the ID's, one with the processing times and one with the due dates of each order in the queue.

I have tried adding and removing info to a LinkedList, but this did not work. Does anyone know how I could get the information I need?

Comment: Why don't you specify what doesn't work for you? Are you unable to access queue agents? Is exporting to Excel not working for you? What code are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your event, simply loop across all agents in the queue and write a dbase query to insert data for them using the `insertInto` [syntax](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/connectivity/querying.html#insert).

Could look like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<queue.size(); i++) {
    MyAgent currentAgent = queue.get(i);
    insertInto(myDbaseTable)
        .columns(myDbaseTable.column1, myDbaseTable.column2)
        .values(currentAgent.someInfo, currentAgent.otherInfo)
        .execute();
}
```